# Spacy matcher - how to find tokens with matching custom attribute

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I have a custom token attribute `._.group_id`, which is some `int` value. I want to create a pattern which looks for tokens that have the same value for `group_id`, without explicitly referencing what the value is. So for example, something like this:

```
pattern = [{'LOWER': 'hello', '_': {'group_id': 4}}, {'LOWER': 'world', '_': {'group_id': 4}}]
```

But instead of specifying `'group_id': 4`, all I care about is that the tokens in the pattern have the *same* value for `group_id` (whatever that may be). So rather than just matching all instances of 'hello world', there is an additional constraint that all the tokens must have the same `group_id`. Is this sort of functionality possible in spacy? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly in the matcher.

What you can do is pass the results of a matcher to the function, and with that you can check for any conditions you can describe in code, including things like whether tokens have the same custom attribute. Take a look at [the docs on `on_match` rules](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#on_match).